# Sqlite Combine two databases of same schema excluding duplicates

Tags: sqlite, insert, sql-insert

I know this can be done via insert or ignore, but that command requires either primary keys defined or unique indexes. Both of which increase the database size by about 40% larger, which in my special case is not possible.

I am also constrained by low end hardware. Is anyone aware of an alternate method to merge two databases of the same schema in SQLite and exclude duplicates?

I don't need anything special, I'm just worried about entire line duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new table for each pair of tables of the 2 databases use `UNION` which removes full duplicate rows.
For example, if you have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE table1(col1 INTEGER, col2 TEXT);
CREATE TABLE table2(col1 INTEGER, col2 TEXT);
```

you can create a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE table3(col1 INTEGER, col2 TEXT);
```

and insert the rows of `table1` and `table2`:

```
INSERT INTO table3(col1, col2) 
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION 
SELECT * FROM table2
```

Or create the new table directly:

```
CREATE TABLE table3 AS 
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION 
SELECT * FROM table2
```

If you want to insert in `table1` only the rows from `table2` that do not exist in `table1` use `EXCEPT` which also removes the duplicates of `table2`:

```
INSERT INTO table1(col1, col2) 
SELECT * FROM table2
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM table1
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=6cc7cb275359b084efe1d1dd9db01d8b).